# Outer joining two dataframes using two fields as the key

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2 which look like:

df1

```
Code   ID       Dept Score Comp
AA   3456  Marketing     5    5
AV   3467    Finance     7    8
TG   5437      Admin     8    4
DF   3487    Finance     9    9
```

df2

```
ID          Dept   Pay
3467     Finance   YES    
5437       Admin    NO
9537  Operations   YES
```

I would like to outer join the 2 dataframes using the `ID` and `Dept` fields (which are present in both dataframes) to join the dataframes.  This would result in the following desired output:

df1 + df2

```
   Code     ID       Dept Score Comp    ID       Dept   Pay
     AA   3456  Marketing     5    5   NaN        NaN   NaN
     AV   3467    Finance     7    8  3467    Finance   YES 
     TG   5437      Admin     8    4  5437      Admin    NO
     DF   3487    Finance     9    9   NaN        NaN   NaN
    NaN    NaN        NaN   NaN  NaN  9537 Operations   YES
```

I have looked at trying to use:

```
result = df1.append(df2, sort=False)
```

But can't see how I can use the `ID` and `Dept` fields as the keys when joining the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to outer join use `merge`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on=['ID','Dept'], right_on = ['ID','Dept'])
```

There is a general guideline concerning this topic in the pandas docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge` that automatically detects the intersection of columns in the two dataframes:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer")
print(df3)
```

```
  Code    ID        Dept  Score  Comp  Pay
0   AA  3456   Marketing    5.0   5.0  NaN
1   AV  3467     Finance    7.0   8.0  YES
2   TG  5437       Admin    8.0   4.0   NO
3   DF  3487     Finance    9.0   9.0  NaN
4  NaN  9537  Operations    NaN   NaN  YES
```